# Differential of a function and linear form with dual basis vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, duality-theorems

I made confusions with the definition of function differential and notations with basis vectors $\{e_{i}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\}$ and dual basis vectors $\{e^{i}=\text{d}x^{i}\}$.

Let's take the differential of a function $f(x,y,z)$ :

$$df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\text{d}x+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\text{d}y+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\text{d}z$$

$df$ Differential of the function $f$ is so an application from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Now I would like to do the link between the expression of $df$ and its expression with basis vectors and dual basis vectors.

How can I express $df$ with dual basis ? this may be :

$$df=a_1\vec{e^1}+a_2\vec{e^2}+a_3\vec{e^3}$$

with $a_i=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}$ and $\vec{e^{i}}=\text{d}x^{i}$

??

How to do the link between $df$ and its expression in starting basis vectors, i.e $\{e_{i}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\}$ ?

Surely, I made confusion supposing $df$ is a linear form and so not a classic vector.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do in fact is to use the [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) with the standard dot product for each linear functional $df(p)$, obtaining then a vector ${\rm grad}\,f(p)$ satisfying $$df(p)(v) = \langle {\rm grad}\,f(p),v\rangle,$$for all $v$. We have $$\begin{align} df &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\, dz \\ {\rm grad}\,f &=  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial }{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\, \frac{\partial }{\partial z}. \end{align}$$Bear in mind this duality, because $df$ is not a vector per se (you can call it a covector, if you want).

Comment: From where this formula for grad f arises?

Comment: if i do the standard dot product between $grad f(p)$ and $v$, I get : $$df(p)(v)=<gradf(p),v>=$$  $$\begin{align} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\, \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}. \end{align}$$ how can I get the expression of $df(p)(v)$ from this, i.e : $$\begin{align} df(p)(v) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,v_x\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,v_y\,dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,v_z\, dz\end{align}$$ ??

Comment: @youpilat13 $df(p)(v)$ is a real number, so you don't have these $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ in the last expression. Also, $\partial v_x/\partial x$ don't make sense, since $v$ is a fixed vector. What you want is $dx(v) = v_x$, etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "gradient circulation". The moral of the history is that if $f\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, then for each $p \in \Bbb R^n$, we have a linear functional $df(p)\colon \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, which corresponds to a vector ${\rm grad}\,f(p) \in \Bbb R^n$ via $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$. 

You can write $dx^i(v) = dx^i(v^j \partial_j)= v^j dx^i(\partial_j) = v^j \delta_j^i = v^i$ (I'd avoid using $x$ for an index)

Comment: ok just a last question : in the expression $$df(p)(v) = \langle {\rm grad}\,f(p),v\rangle,$$, in order to find the expression $$\begin{align} df(p)(v) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,v_x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,v_y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,v_z\end{align}$$, can I write the vector $\vec{v}$ like : $\vec{v}=v_{i}\,\text{d}x^{i}$ where $v_{i}$ are the covariant components of vector $\vec{v}$ and $\text{d}x^{i}$ are dual basis vectors ??

Comment: with the definitions :$$\begin{align} df &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\, dz \\ {\rm grad}\,f &=  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial }{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\, \frac{\partial }{\partial z}. \end{align}$$ Could we consider $df$ like a covector (i.e a linear form) and $\vec{grad}\,f$ like a classic vector ? so what's the nature of vector $\vec{v}$, is it classic vector or covector ? thanks, I don't want to bore you too much.

Comment: $v$ is a **vector**. What you can write as $v_i dx^i$ is the functional "multiply by $v$".

Comment: just a little RECTIFICATION  : we have $\text{d}x^{i}(\vec{v})=v^i$ because
$\text{d}x^{i}(v^{j}\partial_j)=\delta_{ij}v^j=v^{i}$ ; $v^{i}$ is the contravariant component of $\vec{v}$